# Multidimensional array looping (PHP) - a better way?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, loops, multidimensional-array

Is there a better/more efficient way to loop through this data?

I need to loop through the array data with the 'Name' first and the 'ListID' second but the external API request generates the array as per the code below (the other way round).

```
// Array Data
$csList = array(
    array(
        'ListID' => 'BGERFwQTrHoseE4sweebqwyAxuJ9YU',
        'Name' => 'Monthly Newsletter Subscribers'
    ),
    array(
        'ListID' => 'kHdUQMbELgMyojuATz9Dsbxz3WViVo',
        'Name' => 'Special Mailout'
    )
);

// Generate Array Varaibles
foreach($csList as $array => $values) { 
    foreach($values as $k => $v) { 
        for($i = 1; $i < count($csList); $i++) {
            $csListData[$k][] = $v;
        }
    }            
}

// Loop Data
for($i = 0; $i < count($csList); $i++) {
    echo $csListData['Name'][$i].'<br>';
    echo $csListData['ListID'][$i].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: why? using a for loop is okay

Comment: Where is the problem? The input array looks pretty well, so I don't understand why you try to rearrange it.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear why you're rearranging the data. Loop over the array and access whatever keys you want in whatever order you want.

```
 $csList = array(
    array(
        'ListID' => 'BGERFwQTrHoseE4sweebqwyAxuJ9YU',
        'Name' => 'Monthly Newsletter Subscribers'
    ),
    array(
        'ListID' => 'kHdUQMbELgMyojuATz9Dsbxz3WViVo',
        'Name' => 'Special Mailout'
    )
);

foreach ($csList as $item) {
    echo $item['Name'].'<br>';
    echo $item['ListID'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense but why doesn't the foreach code work with the array returned from my api request? I wrote my own array for the post earlier which it works fine with!

`Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ListID] => BGERFwQTrHoseE4sweebqwyAxuJ9YU [Name] => Monthly Newsletter Subscribers ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [ListID] => kHdUQMbELgMyojuATz9Dsbxz3WViVo [Name] => Special Mailout ) )`

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `for` loop is useless. You can use the `$array` key to get your array as wanted :

```
foreach($csList as $array => $values) { 
    foreach($values as $k => $v) { 
      $csListData[$k][$array] = $v;  
    }            
}

// Loop Data
for($i = 0, $c = count($csList); $i <$c; $i++) {
    echo '<br>';
    echo $csListData['Name'][$i].'<br>';
    echo $csListData['ListID'][$i].'<br>';
}
```

Also, moving the `count()` out of the check will avoid to count at every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Array Data
$csList = array(
   array(
    'ListID' => 'BGERFwQTrHoseE4sweebqwyAxuJ9YU',
    'Name' => 'Monthly Newsletter Subscribers'
   ),
   array(
    'ListID' => 'kHdUQMbELgMyojuATz9Dsbxz3WViVo',
    'Name' => 'Special Mailout'
  )
);
```

You can do as follow:

```
$newCsList = array();
$newCsList = array_map(function ($val){
     return array_reverse($val,true);
},$csList);
```

The result is like:

```
**Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                        [Name] => Monthly Newsletter Subscribers 
                        [ListID] => BGERFwQTrHoseE4sweebqwyAxuJ9YU 
                     ) 
        [1] => Array ( 
                        [Name] => Special Mailout 
                        [ListID] => kHdUQMbELgMyojuATz9Dsbxz3WViVo 
                     ) 
  )**
```

But for taking each element you can do:

```
 $newCsList = array();
$newCsList = array_map(function ($val){
     $my_test_ary = array_reverse($val);
     echo $my_test_ary['Name'].'<br/>'.$my_test_ary['ListId'];

},$csList);
```

Comment: Well, you're just re-creating the same array ? It's not what OP wants

Comment: to echo  each element we can do that inside array_map after reversing array for example $my_test_ary = array_reverse($val); echo $my_test_ary['Name'].